# jQuery memory game – if (text != text) {reload page}

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a little memory game, and I have some jQuery issues:
The game is made with code only, so the pairs are made out by html-symbols. What I want is to reload the page if the symbols of two clicked "tiles" are not the same.
I tried with `if  ($(this).text() != $(".active").text()) {
                location.reload();
                }`, it doesn't seem to work. I am a jQuery n00b, so sorry if I have made obvious, stupid errors ^__^

Link: http://www.carlpapworth.com/htmlove/memory.html

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
<div id="headerTitle"><a href="index.html">&lt;html<span class="heart">&hearts;</span>ve&gt;</a>
            </div>
            <div id="help">
                <h2>?</h2>
                <div id="helpInfo">
                    <p>How many tiles are there? Let's see [calculating] 25...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    <div id="reward">
        <div id="rewardContainer">
            <div id="rewardBG" class="heart">&hearts;
            </div>
            <p>OMG, this must be luv<br><a href="index.html" class="exit">x</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="pageWrap">
            <div id="mainContent">
            <!-- DON'T BE A CHEATER !-->
                <table id="memory">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="pair1"><a>&Psi;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair2"><a>&para;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair3"><a>&Xi;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair1"><a>&Psi;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair4"><a >&otimes;</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="pair5"><a>&spades;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair6"><a >&Phi;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair7"><a>&sect;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair8"><a>&clubs;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair4"><a>&otimes;</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="pair9"><a>&Omega;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair2"><a>&para;</a></td>
                        <td id="goal">
                <a href="#reward" class="heart">&hearts;</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="pair10"><a>&copy;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair9"><a>&Omega;</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="pair11"><a>&there4;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair8"><a>&clubs;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair12"><a>&dagger;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair6"><a>&Phi;</a></td>
                        <td class="pair11"><a>&there4;</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="pair12">&dagger;</a></td>
                        <td><a class="pair5">&spades;</a></td>
                        <td><a class="pair10">&copy;</a></td>
                        <td><a class="pair3">&Xi;</a></td>
                        <td><a class="pair7">&sect;</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <!-- DON'T BE A CHEATER !-->
            </div>
    </div> <!-- END Page Wrap -->
    <footer>
        <div class="heartCollection">
            <p>collect us if u need luv:<p>
            <ul>
                <li><a id="collection1">&hearts;</a></li>
                <li><a id="collection2">&hearts;</a></li>
                <li><a id="collection3">&hearts;</a></li>
                <li><a id="collection4">&hearts;</a></li>
                <li><a id="collection5">&hearts;</a></li>
                <li><a id="collection6">&hearts;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="credits">with love from Popm0uth ©2012</div>
    </footer>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('td').click(openCard);

    function openCard(){
        $(this).addClass('opened');
        $(this).find('a').addClass('visible');
        if ($(".active")[0]){
            function match(){ 
                if  ($(this).text() != $(".active").text()) {
                location.reload();
                }       
                else {
                $(".active").removeClass("active");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just hide the tiles again so you don't have to keep refreshing the page?

Comment: i don't get it, are you sure you want to reload the page? why??

Comment: have you try with strict comparison `!==` ?

Comment: You are never executing the function `match`. In fact, the function declaration is unnecessary here. Remove it and put the body directly into the `if` block.

Comment: try to store these in variables like var a = $(this).text(); var b = $(".active").text(); and alert it and see what it gets.

Comment: I just thought that refreshing it was an easy way of "reloading" the game. I guess changing the css would be fine as well. @felix Kling, I will try that!

So it is fine to have an "if" within another "if"?

Comment: You can have as many nested `if`, `for`, `while`, etc as you want. At some stage your code might be easy to understand anymore, but technically it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
if ($(".active")[0]){

            if  ($(this).text() != $(".active").text()) {
            location.reload();
            }       
            else {
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going wrong here. First, you are declaring your `match()` function within your `if ($(".active")[0])` block, which is incorrect. You should be declaring it outside the `if` block, even outside the `openCard` function, and call it using `match()`.

Also you will need to pass in your `this` object after storing it in a variable, otherwise it will not be accessible. Something like this:

```
var thisCard = $(this).text();
var activeCard = $(".active").text();

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('td').click(openCard);

    function openCard(){
        var that = $(this);
        that.addClass('opened');
        that.find('a').addClass('visible');
        if ($(".active")[0]){
            match(that);
        }
        else {
            that.addClass("active");
        }
    }
    function match(that){ 
        if  (that.text() != $(".active").text()) {
            location.reload();
        }       
        else {
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you use the var "that"?

Comment: No particular reason, it's just what I thought of at the time. You should probably change it to something more meaningful.

Comment: I didn't mean the var name, rather using a variable. I am quite new to jQuery, so I wondered why it was preferable here? Than writing '$("this")' instead :)

SORRY! You wrote it in your post ;) silly me!

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `function match()` inside  `if ($(".active")[0])` block but you are not calling it anywhere. That is why, it will never go inside that function.

By the way, try using FireBug (if you are using Firefox) or Developer Tools (if you are using chrome) to debug your javascript so that you'll have an idea where the problem is. It will make debugging easier.